# JSONPath issues with Python and jsonpath_ng (Parse error near token ?)

Tags: python, jsonpath, jsonpath-ng

I'm trying to work with jsonpath_ng Python library. For most of the JSONPath filters I usually use it works.
However, I'm struggling with a simple filter clause. It can be summarized in 2 lines.

```
from jsonpath_ng.ext import parse
jsonpath_expression = parse(f"$.jobs.*.jobSummary.[?(@.storagePolicy.storagePolicyName=='{SPname}')].sizeOfApplication")
```

My JSON payload is this one:

```
{
"processinginstructioninfo": {
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "WebServer",
            "value": "IDM-COMMSERVE"
        }
    ]
},
"totalRecordsWithoutPaging": 161,
"jobs": [
    {
        "jobSummary": {
            "sizeOfApplication": 65552265428,
            "vsaParentJobID": 28329591,
            "commcellId": 2,
            "backupSetName": "defaultBackupSet",
            "opType": 59,
            "totalFailedFolders": 0,
            "totalFailedFiles": 0,
            "alertColorLevel": 0,
            "jobAttributes": 288232025419153408,
            "jobAttributesEx": 67108864,
            "isVisible": true,
            "localizedStatus": "Completed",
            "isAged": false,
            "totalNumOfFiles": 0,
            "jobId": 28329592,
            "jobSubmitErrorCode": 0,
            "sizeOfMediaOnDisk": 34199,
            "currentPhase": 0,
            "status": "Completed",
            "lastUpdateTime": 1661877467,
            "percentSavings": 99.99995,
            "localizedOperationName": "Snap Backup",
            "statusColor": "black",
            "pendingReason": "",
            "errorType": 0,
            "backupLevel": 2,
            "jobElapsedTime": 59,
            "jobStartTime": 1661877408,
            "currentPhaseName": "",
            "jobType": "Snap Backup",
            "isPreemptable": 0,
            "backupLevelName": "Incremental",
            "attemptStartTime": 0,
            "pendingReasonErrorCode": "",
            "appTypeName": "Virtual Server",
            "percentComplete": 100,
            "averageThroughput": 27472.637,
            "localizedBackupLevelName": "Incremental",
            "currentThroughput": 0,
            "subclientName": "default",
            "destClientName": "desktop-1058kvf",
            "jobEndTime": 1661877467,
            "dataSource": {
                "dataSourceId": 0
            },
            "subclient": {
                "clientName": "desktop-1058kvf",
                "instanceName": "VMInstance",
                "backupsetId": 161,
                "commCellName": "idm-commserve",
                "instanceId": 2,
                "subclientId": 235,
                "clientId": 71,
                "appName": "Virtual Server",
                "backupsetName": "defaultBackupSet",
                "applicationId": 106,
                "subclientName": "default"
            },
            "storagePolicy": {
                "storagePolicyName": "IDM-Metallic-Replica_ReplicationPlan",
                "storagePolicyId": 78
            },
            "destinationClient": {
                "clientId": 71,
                "clientName": "desktop-1058kvf",
                "displayName": "idm-laptop1"
            },
            "userName": {
                "userName": "admin",
                "userId": 1
            },
            "clientGroups": [
                {
                    "clientGroupId": 4,
                    "clientGroupName": "Laptop Clients"
                },
                {
                    "clientGroupId": 46,
                    "clientGroupName": "Clients For Commserv LiveSync"
                },
                {
                    "clientGroupId": 47,
                    "clientGroupName": "idm-vcsa"
                },
                {
                    "clientGroupId": 55,
                    "clientGroupName": "Laptop plan test clients"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

I need to get just the "sizeOfApplication" parameter for every object with a particular "storagePolicyName". That's it. Say, in this case, that the "storagePolicyName" I'm looking values for is "IDM-Metallic-Replica_ReplicationPlan" as an example.
I usually go to [My favourite JSONPath site](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com) to test the JSONpath I use, and this one
"$.jobs.*.jobSummary.[?(@.storagePolicy.storagePolicyName=='IDM-Metallic-Replica_ReplicationPlan')].sizeOfApplication" works.
But, on Python side, I keep getting "jsonpath_ng.exceptions.JsonPathParserError: Parse error at 1:21 near token ? (?)" errors.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you!

Mattia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that `jsonpath_ng` is being stricter to the JSONPath proposal than the other parsers you have tried.

The first problem is that there shouldn't be a `.` immediately before a filter condition `[?(...)]`. So the first step is to remove the `.` after `jobSummary` in `jobSummary.[?(@storagePolicy...`.

I made that change to your JSONPath expression, and used `jsonpath_ng` to run it on your sample data. The parser error had gone, but it returned no matches. So it's still not right.

From reading the [JSONPath proposal](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/), it's not clear if you can use a filter operator such as `[?(...)]` on an object, or only on an array. When used on an array it would return all elements of the array that match the filter. If a JSONPath parser does support a filter on an object, then it seems it returns the object if the filter matches and an empty list of matches otherwise.

I would guess that `jsonpath_ng` only permits filters on arrays. So let's modify your JSONPath expression to only use filters on arrays. Your JSON has an array in `$.jobs`, and within each element of this array you want to look within the `jobSummary` object for a `storagePolicy` with `storagePolicyName=={SPname}`. So the following JSONPath expression should return the matching job:

```
$.jobs[?(@.jobSummary.storagePolicy.storagePolicyName=='{SPname}')]
```

What we then want to do is to get the value of the `sizeOfApplication` property within the `jobSummary` object within each matching job. Note that the matches returned by the above JSONPath expression are elements of the `jobs` array, not `jobSummary` objects. We can't just select `sizeOfApplication` because we're one level further up than we were before. We need to go back into the `jobSummary` object to get the `sizeOfApplication`:

```
$.jobs[?(@.jobSummary.storagePolicy.storagePolicyName=='{SPname}')].jobSummary.sizeOfApplication
```

I used `jsonpath_ng` to run this JSONPath expression on your sample data and it gave me the output `[65552265428]`, which seems to be the expected output.

Comment: Thank you Luke! This answer provided me not only the solution, but a better understanding on JSONPath behind the hood and the library jsonpath_ng. Very appreciated!